# Rudin Functional Analysis Chapter 3 Problem 19

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-hulls

Suppose $K$ is a compact convex set in $\mathbb R^n$. Prove that every $x\in K$ is a convex combination of at most $n+1$ extreme points of K.

I know that in $\mathbb R^n$ if $E\subset \mathbb R^n$ then for any $x\in co(E)$, $x$ lies in the convex hull of some subset of E which contains at most $n+1$ points and also by $Krein-Milman ~Theorem$ we know that $K= \overline{co}(E(K))$ but i am not able to linkup these two statements.

Any type of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You choose the extremal points AFTER choosing $x$!!! Fixed one extremal point as the "origin", you need $n$ more to have a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: i didn't get that. can you please elaborate